# My loop will not work with PHP (DateTime conversion)

Tags: php, loops, datetime

Hello :) I have been trying to work on this piece of PHP script, to select all of the DateTime rows that meet certain criteria, then to calculate the time difference from then to current time.

My PHP script just echos "44 years ago." When I have more then one record in the database, and the echo is totally wrong, I do not have a record in the database that old.

I do know that I can echo the appropriate datetimes inside the selection loop, the select criteria does work.

Some help is appreciated. :)

My PHP code is below:

```
     <?php

//AJAX REQUEST
$Following_ID = $_GET['Following_ID'];
//connection infi
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","PASS","TABLE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 //SQL to select all fields from appointment table
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Followers
WHERE Following_ID='$Following_ID' AND Follow_Status='acce' AND Followers_Requested_Game NOT LIKE '%$Following_ID%' AND (Follower_Game='truth' OR Follower_Game='rate') ORDER BY Game_Time DESC");

//echo all in array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

$time = $row['Game_Time'];
humanTiming ($time);
echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago';
}

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}

}


//close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

I have the solution here:

```
<?php

//AJAX REQUEST
$Following_ID = $_GET['Following_ID'];
//connection infi
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","PASS","TABLE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 //SQL to select all fields from appointment table
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Followers
WHERE Following_ID='$Following_ID' AND Follow_Status='acce' AND Followers_Requested_Game NOT LIKE '%$Following_ID%' AND (Follower_Game='truth' OR Follower_Game='rate') ORDER BY Game_Time DESC");

//echo all in array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

$times = $row['Game_Time'];
$time = strtotime($times);
humanTiming ($time);
echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago';
}

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}


//close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This code couldn't possibly work as-writtein. You're defininig a function INSIDE the while loop, which'd cause it die on the second iteration with a "cannot redeclare functioN" error.

Comment: I thought that might be a problem too, I could just call the function inside the loop with the function outside of it?

Comment: yes. that'd work fine. And if you're rearranging things, you might want to fix up your gaping wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, before someone pwns your server.

Comment: I will do that once I get the script working correctly. I have updated my code example, it seems to not work still. It echos 44 years ago

Comment: Which'd correponds to your date being Jan 1/1970, which is 44 years ago... e.g. unix timestamp = 0

Comment: Is that `Game_time` value from the DB a date/datetime value, or a unix timestamp? if it's a date/datetime, it's coming out as a string, which you're then using in a math context. e.g. `'2014-02-14' - integer`.

Comment: I have dates in there to test it out, I have the timestamp 2014-02-14 18:30:00 and it still returns 44 years. I have 100 records in the database for the criteria and it also only echos one selection

Comment: Game_Time is a DateTime row inside the database table

Comment: This solution works the edited version :)

Comment: Because, at its core, this question is asking how to convert time from `Y-m-d` to a unix timestamp, the answer is Read The Manual.  This question is a useless and should have been self-solved by basic debugging, issue isolation, and online manual reading.  Please delete this question because it has no value to future SO readers.  In the future, isolate your issues and only post a minimal question, so that readers don't waste time reading your entire file.  (...and you are not meant to add solutions/answers to your question; answers are to be posted as answers.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as I don't yet have 50 rep so I'll have to do that here but it seems that @Marc B is right when he said:

> ($time) correponds to your date being Jan 1/1970

Whenever I'm trying to do something with a date and it pulls through that date (1st Jan 1970) I know that I'm not matching up the formats of time. So I'm advising 3 things:

**1) Bug test - eliminating all possibilities**

- Output `$time` from this segment of your code: `$time = $row['Game_Time'];`
- Check that this is coming out as a unix timestamp (currently 1392430174 as I write)
- As `time()` is in unix timestamp format this will mean that you are deducting correctly and the line `$time = time() - $time;` will also be in unix timestamp format.

**2) The probable**

If I had to take a guess I would say that `$time` or `$row['Game_Time']` is not in unix timestamp format which means you should convert it using `strtotime($time)` and then do the calculation (`$time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment`). Test the output of this. With coding one thing is for absolute certain - you will get bugs. So you have to work on the system of deducing the answer based on a series of logical tests. It really is like trapping a bug with a glass!

**3) A few tips**

I would do yourself a favour and avoid potential problems with variable names. Why not call this line:

```
$time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
```

like this:

```
$time_difference = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
```

.. or whatever as I have previously had problems in redefining a string as part of itself like this - particularly when passing parameters.

Also wouldn't the `$tokens` array be more standardised switching the seconds to the value and the time name, e.g. "year" to the key. And maybe use something easier to read so there are no mistakes with the numbers, e.g.

```
$tokens = array();
$tokens['second'] = 1;
$tokens['minute'] = 60*$second;
$tokens['hour'] = 60*$minute;
$tokens['day'] = 24*$hour;
$tokens['week'] = 7*$day;
$tokens['month'] = 30*$day;
$tokens['year'] = 365*$day;
```

Just suggestions but the main thing is that if it is just you working with it you can find yourself around, etc. Oh and get anything in the open in a function - just call it from the outside. All good stuff though!_

Comment: Thanks for your input! I got it working, I just needed to format the DateTime out of string to Unix timestamp

Comment: @user2921824 - no worries .. ponder on my other suggestions though.. and for anyone else out there that is getting back Jan 1 1970 in any part of their workings rather than the date they want the problem is usually that a date format is not in unix timestamp. `strtotime($time)` will help_